# TOTP key extraction from Xfinity Authenticator

Tags: root-access, backup

I've been trying (and failing) to find where the Xfinity Authenticator app stores the TOTP secret. Nothing in any files in shared_prefs looks like a TOTP key, and I'm beginning to suspect that it's being stored elsewhere. In particular, the com.comcast.xfinityauthenticator_preferences.xml file has the following value in it:

`<boolean name="keyCredentialStoredInVault" value="true" />`

Any guidance on where to go from here would be appreciated.

Comment: Could probably in Databases, no backup, or files directory. Check them too.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified that I've been through all of the files inside /data/data/com.comcast.xfinityauthenticator/ and none of the strings that look like likely keys produce codes that match the output of the app.

Comment: Isn't there a place in the device's secure storage (can remember the name currently – keystore?)? I'm using andOTP and it offers that. And I've no idea how to extract stuff from there.

Comment: @Izzy The [Android keystore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore)?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yepp, that one – thanks for linking!

Comment: @Izzy Well, if that's indeed what this app is doing, then it looks like I'm out of luck.

Comment: Only ways to find out are: checking the source (uh? not a FOSS app? Ouch.), asking the dev – who might even be able to offer some export feature, maybe… Uh, Comcast? That the cable-comcast? Then good luck…